# resource controller, pass multiple parameters using AJAX

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I am using `Laravel` for the first time to create an API to be accessed using AJAX from an angular.js single page app. I can't figure out how to configure controller and URL to pass more than one argument to any of the methods

Have routes configured for my API group as follows

```
Route::group(array('prefix' => 'api/v1'), function(){
    Route::resource('event', 'EventController');    
});
```

`EventController` methods are all working as documented, however, I have a need to send a start and end date as params for retrieving my events.

I also placed  `missingMethod($parameters = array())` in controller but never had any luck getting it to fire

I tried adding an extra argument to show method, `function show($start, $end)` but can't get AJAX URL figured out to make it work.
Have tried a variety of approaches:

```
/myapp/api/v1/event/param1/param2
/myapp/api/v1/event/param1,param2
 /* hoping missingMethod($parameters = array()) might get this one*/
/myapp/api/v1/event/[param1,param2]
```

For the most part, most attempts got an exception thrown that `show` was missing the second argument.

I finally settled on using conventional query string and testing `Input::get()` in my `index()` function.

```
/myapp/api/v1/event?param1=1&param2=2
```

I also tried several approaches to adding `Route::get('/event')` with wildcards before registering the resource to no avail.

I guess there is a relatively simple way to have a resource controller method have more than one argument, and if not how can the HTTP request be configured so that `missingMethod` receives an array?

Comment: @maik-lowrey this doesn't really seem like a consequential edit, was this worth bumping the post?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add that specific route above the `resource` (I'm assuming you are using `GET` for your ajax requests):

```
Route::group(array('prefix' => 'api/v1'), function(){
    Route::get('event/{start}/{end}', 'EventController@index');
    Route::resource('event', 'EventController');    
});
```

In your controller, make your parameters optional so you can use the same controller action for both routes, `api/v1/event` and `api/v1/event`:

```
<?php

class EventController extends BaseController {

    public function index($start = null, $end = null)
    {
        if (isset($start) && isset($end)) {
            return $this->eventsRepository->byDate($start, $end);
        }

        return $this->eventsRepository->all();
    }

}
```

If you want to be more specific about the `start` and `end` wildcards format, you can use where:

```
Route::get('event/{start}/{end}', 'EventController@index')
         ->where([
            'start' => 'regexp-here', 
            'end' => 'regexp-here'
           ]);
```

Comment: I sure could have sworn I tried this approach, but it's working....thanks!. Can I create a custom method that isn't `show,index,update` etc then and use that in the `@myMethod` in `Route` ?

Comment: Yes, you can bind all methods you want with `Route::get()`. Also take a look a `Route::controller()`, might be useful too: http://laravel.com/docs/controllers#restful-controllers

Comment: ok..thanks. Have been all over those docs today. Literally just started with laravel yesterday but already have what you gave me working. Next step will be figure out repositories but have plenty to do on my front end now that data flowing the way I need it